# How to use a PHP code in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I want to use PHP code in JavaScript, but it doesn't work:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
           function edit(pollNo)
           {
               <?php
                   $result = mysql_query( 'CALL ret_poll('.pollNo.')' );
                   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                   echo 'document.poll.pollTitle.value='.$row['title'];
               ?>
           }
        </script>
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server side, JavaScript on the client side.

Comment: You _cannot_ run PHP in JavaScript. What you _can_ do is generate JavaScript with PHP. It's unclear which you're doing--depending on how that file is served to the browser, it could be either. Please tell us more precisely _how_ it doesn't work. Your question is far too vague.

Answer (score 4):

You could use jQuery to perform an AJAX request to a PHP page that executes the PHP code and pass along the arguments from the JavaScript function.
Check out the jQuery website for more information on this subject:
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

The big problem in your code is that JavaScript runs on the Client Side and PHP runs on the Server Side. That's why it's impossible to mix these two like this.

I wrote this for you, but I haven't tested it. I'm pretty sure it gives you an idea of how to implement this:

**getpollinfo.php**

```
<?php
if ( IsSet( $_GET['poll'] ) ) {

  /* Connect to MySQL here */

  $result = mysql_query( 'CALL ret_poll(' . intval( $_GET['poll'] ) . ')' );
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

  echo json_encode($row);
}
?>
```

**JavaScript code** (assuming you've loaded the jQuery framework)

```
function edit(pollNo)
{
  $.get('getpollinfo.php', { 'poll' : pollNo }, function(data) {
     $('#pollTitle').html(data.title);
  });
}
```

Comment: Could You write this by jQuery and AJAX for me ?

Comment: @Javad: This is not a free coding service and an actual solution  depends on more than just the pieces of code you gave us. You will benefit much more if you *learn* it yourself. It is not difficult.

Comment: @Javad: I wrote a small example based up on your code. I encourage you not to use this code in production, but learn from it and write your own code.

Comment: @Javad Yousefi Don't want to be rude, but this is not the place for a "give me a code that works".

Answer (score 2):

Javed, its not that you can't use php in javascript. However the uses are very limited.

See an example

```
alert('<?php echo "hi"; ?>');
```

Once the server renders this, the script will be

```
`alert('hi');` //SO it will alert `hi` now
```

Mostly, you can use PHP and javascript mixture to create a script you want to run on the run time

For example

```
<script>
   <?php
   $location = $_SESSION['logged'] ? 'admin.php' : 'index.php';
   ?>
   window.location('<?php echo $location; ?>');
</script>
```

Or Something like this

```
<script>
    <?PHP if($test==true) { ?>
        function test() {
            //do something;
        }
    <?php } else { ?>
        function test() {
            //do something else but not the previous one
        }
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```

---

However, What you are trying is **TRYING TO USE PHP CODES AS JAVASCRIPT** Which is not possible !!!!!!!!

Instead, you can use AJAX, as other answers suggest, for a workaround.

A little demo of your probable solution is

FILE: myMYSQLPROCESSING.php

```
        // Your connections and other above                
        $result = mysql_query( 'CALL ret_poll('.$_POST['pollno'].')' );
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo $row['title'];
```

JS

```
    function edit(pollNo)
    {
        $.post("myMYSQLPROCESSING.php",
            { "pollno" : pollNo },
            function(data) {
                // Now data, will contain whatever you echo in myMYSQLPROCESSING.php
                // May be a success message or error message

                // and do whatever you want with the response

               document.poll.pollTitle.value=data; //in your case something like this
            }
        );
    }
```

This is a jQuery code, if you are not familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript = client side.

Php = server side.

You can't combine them the way you use, you will need to use an ajax to do what you want.

The sequence will be:

- javascript: your edit function
- javascript: ajax request to php script
- php: perform query and return result
- javascript: handle the response

Answer (score 2):

First you have to understand that PHP runs on the server side and JavaScript on the client. Hence you cannot directly invoke PHP code in a JavaScript function by just putting it there.

When the client makes a request, the PHP interpreter executes the code and produces some output. This output is sent to the browser and there the JavaScript code is executed. PHP's job is already done at this point.

---

You achieve what you want with [*Ajax*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) (though I think you have to learn more about [*JavaScript*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide), [*PHP*](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php) and [*HTTP*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) first).

But to give you an example (using the [*jQuery*](http://jquery.com/) library):

```
function edit(pollNo){
    $.get('get_poll.php',{id: pollNo}, function(data) {
        $('input[name="pollTitle"]').val(data);
    });
}
```

Where your PHP file looks like:

```
// db connection...
$result = mysql_query( 'CALL ret_poll('.mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'].')' );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['title'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. And you'll never be able to. It would break a very big hole in the security wall.
By the way you can use the AJAX technique and call a PHP file via Javascript.

References:

- [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

Comment: Thank You,But I dont khnow AJAX

Comment: @Charliepiga: w3schools **is not** the W3C! I'd downvote that comment if that were possible. [You need help.](http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do what your saying, you will end up just rendering the page with that specific Javascript code version.

If you really want to do that you have to look at the output to see that you need to quote strings in Javascript.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function edit(pollNo)
    {
        <?php
            $result = mysql_query( 'CALL ret_poll('.pollNo.')' );
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            echo 'document.poll.pollTitle.value="'.$row['title'].'"';
        ?>

    }
    </script>
```

Your browser will end up with:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function edit(pollNo)
    {
        document.poll.pollTitle.value="somehardcodedtext";

    }
    </script>
```

You will have to consider escaping quote symbols in the output of `$row['title']` and whether you would rather just call the server using AJAX instead.

Comment: Ok,But I dont khnow any About AJAX and Programming with it