# What is the correct syntax to echo php within javascript

Tags: php, javascript

What is the correct syntax to echo out some php within a javascript function?

Comment: AJAX, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest. In case you don't know: It is not possible to embed PHP code in JavaScript.

Comment: err... Why would you want to do this? The client can't run PHP.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Get the result from a PHP in a page using JS? If yes, in what way? You can use XMLHttpRequest or even `<script src="file.php"></script>` to embed the result of PHP in a page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a php code in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640761/how-to-use-a-php-code-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't directly echo php in your Javascript because, the JS code is executed on the end user machine not on your backend. However you can echo some php code before the end user receives the JS source code, in other words, generate your JS code with php and serve it as .js file.